# Apply Bootstrap CSS class to all HTML elements of given type

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to set the Bootstrap `btn` class to all `<button>` elements without doing it manually on every button. I know I can add custom style to all buttons like that:

`button {
    ...some-properties...
}`

but I would need something like that:

`button {
    .btn
}`

I know I can achieve that with LESS, but my question is, if it is the only method to achieve that or is it possible using only CSS? I have also found that I can achieve that using jQuery. For what it's worth, I am using AngularJS, maybe AngularUI or AngularStrap would help?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such thing as extending a css class in pure css. The only way to achieve what you want would be to get the source css of bootstrap `.btn` class and add it to all buttons:

```
button {
    // .btn source css
}
```

Even if it works, it's **not a good approach** since Bootstrap may change it in future versions. Css preprocessors like Less and Sass are probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Copying Boostrap source does not sound good for me. I know it's easy with LESS, jQuery,etc, but I want to make sure if it's possible with just CSS.

Comment: Edited to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is  another way except using **Less** in this scenario with **CSS**  you cannot do this whatever you do because **CSS is not CAPABLE of this LEVEL of Abstraction** so Please Use **LESS** I assure you you cannot do this with **CSS** so **don't waste Time a**nd Use LESS
like this:

> button   {
>         .btn;   }